# Signing Apps in Blackberry

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-webworks

I am trying to sign an app by following these instructions:

https://bdsc.webapps.blackberry.com/html5/documentation/ww_publishing/signing_setup_smartphone_apps_...

https://bdsc.webapps.blackberry.com/html5/documentation/ww_publishing/signing_your_smartphone_app_19...

I have done all the steps, and have tried packaging via both Ripple and command line to which I get successful finish messages:

[image]

I place the OTAInstall and StandardInstall folders from the output directory on my server and download and install the app. The icon shows up on the homescreen but when I click to launch it, it states that it **cannot open** because it is **attempting to access a secure API**. What am I doing wrong here I thought the signing process was complete? Or is this even related to the signing process? Any help would be appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: There are 3 keys. All 3 keys must be register with bb server. When I  developed BB app, initially I made the mistake of reg only one key.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the keys, just use Eclipse Helios equipped with BB plugin (you can get it from BB website),
just go to `Window >> Preferences >> BlackBerry Java Plug-in >> Signature tool >> Install New Keys`

then choose your keys (usually you will need the 3 of them (RCR,RRT,RBB)) you will be prompted for the pin no. (use your device's pin no.) and the signing code (you have to remember it) , and you must be connected to the internet when you do this procedure to be able to register the keys to the BB server.
then you will need the BB manager (you can download it from [Here](http://us.blackberry.com/apps-software/desktop/) ) in order to be able to connect your phone to eclipse and you can use it to get the device's pin no.

if you have done all these steps successfully, you should have no problems signing your app, which is as follows:

1- package your app `Rclick on the project >>BB>> package project(s)`

2- Sign your app `Rclick on proj >> BB >> Sign with signature tool ..`

3- Load on Device `Rclick on proj >> BB >> Load Project(s) on Device ..` (while BB desktop "manager" is on)

- to get the signature keys if you don't have them is from [Here](https://www.blackberry.com/SignedKeys/) .
- BTW usually 'attempts to access secure api' is from signing the app. last time I did sign it and still got this message .. I solved that by rewriting the whole thing in a more organized way ( separated screens in different classes ...) and then signed them and worked perfectly from the first try , I hope you won't have to go through that ..

I hope I could help solve your issue completely,
regards,

Comment: also make sure you are using the correct JDE for your device, if your device uses os 6.0 then you should use JDE 6.0 .. the device will give you the same message 'module attempts to access secure api' if you use a newer version than your device's ..

Comment: I'm using the webworks platform and developing in HTML5 and not java. The first two links in the question above deal with signing the app in webworks or the console and not eclipse, I'm not sure if this would apply to a webworks platform?

Comment: hmm I never tried weborks, but practically it should be the same since it works on eclipse, check [THIS (click)](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/subcategories/?userType=21&category=WebWorks+Plug-ins&subCategory=BlackBerry+WebWorks+Plug-in+for+Eclipse)